# External microphone ubuntu

Tags: sound, lubuntu

I have a problem with the built-in microphone of my laptop (ubuntu 16.04). Now I am sure it is a problem with the driver and I have no intention to fix it as it is a pain and I have already wasted enough time on it.

I was wondering though, if using an external microphone could be a solution. In other words: does the fact that the internal microphone is not working imply that any other plugged microphone will not work either?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible, especially since you've claimed the problem is "with the driver".

Comment: by "yes" do you mean "no mic will ever work" ?

Comment: No, I mean, another mic might have exactly the same problem as the old one, whatever it might be. I don't claim to know anything about "any mic" or "ever work".

Comment: Any idea how to fix  the driver issue then? (If it is a driver issue, I am not even sure)

Comment: Well, ...and what about "Now I am sure it is a problem with the driver and I have no intention to fix it..."? To be honest, I don't know what driver is to blame and why, as you've posted zero evidence for the driver claim. A lot of times mics don't seem to work because they are muted. Have you checked?